# Matrix monotonicity $A \ge B$ then $B^{-1} \ge A^{-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

I am wondering if it is true that if in the sense of matrices we have $A \ge B$ that in case both of them are invertible, we also have that $B^{-1} \ge A^{-1}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $A\ge B$?

Comment: Correct the question to show the positive condition.  (Also in the question, answer the user1441) Then show what you have tried.  In this forum, you should not merely state the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am supposing by $A \geq B$, you meant $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, and $A - B$ are positive semi-definite.

Your conjecture is not true. For example, take
\begin{align*}
A = I_{(2)}, \quad B = -I_{(2)},
\end{align*}
then $A - B = 2I_{(2)} \geq 0$, but $B^{-1} - A^{-1} = -2I_{(2)} \leq 0$.

On the other hand, given an additional condition $A \geq B \color{red}{> 0}$, then $B^{-1} \geq A^{-1}$ is indeed true. You can try to prove it.

Comment: +1 to the extra condition.  Even with real numbers, we cannot go from $x>y$ to $y^{-1} > x^{-1}$.

Comment: @GEdgar Exactly. My counterexample could be made that simple.

Comment: @Zhanxiong actually my question was about positive ones, would you mind giving the proof in that case?

Comment: @J.Doe Please follow the advice of GEdgar: you need to edit the question to reveal what you really wants to prove.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to prove that if $0\prec B \preceq A$, then $0 \prec A^{-1} \preceq B^{-1}$.

From $0\prec B\preceq A$ we have that $B\succ 0$ and $A-B\succeq 0$, obviously. We first show that $B\succ0\iff B^{-1}\succ0$; we have $B\succ0 \iff x^*Bx>0\ \forall\,x\neq0$. Introduce $y=Bx$, i.e., $x=B^{-1}y$, which yields
$$  y^*(B^{-1})^*BB^{-1}y >0 \  \forall\,x\neq0 \iff y^*B^{-1}y >0 \  \forall\,x\neq0 \iff B^{-1}\succ 0. $$
Similarly for $A$, i.e., $A\succ 0\iff A^{-1}\succ0$.

Hence, we have $B^{-1}\succ0$ and $A-B\succeq0$. Moreover, we have that $B^{-1}\succ0\implies B^{-1}\succeq0$. Next, we apply the non-strict Schur complement twice on $A-B\succeq0$, i.e.,
$$\left.\begin{aligned} & B^{-1}\succeq0 \\ & A-IBI\succeq0 \end{aligned}\right\}\iff \begin{pmatrix} B^{-1} & I \\ I & A \end{pmatrix}\succeq0 \iff \left\{\begin{aligned} & A^{-1}\succeq0 \\ & B^{-1}-IA^{-1}I\succeq0. \end{aligned}\right.$$
From the last inequality, we have $B^{-1}\succeq A^{-1}$, which together with $A^{-1}\succ0$ gives that $0\prec B\preceq A$ if $B^{-1}\succ A^{-1}\succ0$.

(For strict inequalities, it is even a necessary and sufficient condition).